# error when creating discord bot with discord.py module. I think it's to do with the installation using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, discord, discord.py

If I run the following code in python, I get an error.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "token"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "rps/")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ('ready')

client.run("token")
```

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/timothy/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py",
>   line 822, in _wrap_create_connection
>       return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py",
>   line 804, in create_connection
>       sock, protocol_factory, ssl, server_hostname)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py",
>   line 830, in _create_connection_transport
>       yield from waiter   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py",
>   line 505, in data_received
>       ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py",
>   line 201, in feed_ssldata
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
>   line 689, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/timothy/Documents/coding stuff/python/Test bot/test bot.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       client.run(TOKEN)   File "/Users/timothy/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py",
>   line 571, in run
>       return task.result()   File "/Users/timothy/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py",
>   line 478, in start

I think it's to do with how I installed the package using $conda install discord.py. Does anyone know what I did wrong? python does recognise the module

Comment: Don't ever publish access tokens. Go rotate your tokens so what you posted is revoked.

Comment: Chase I know I changed the token after

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the discord.py module with pip ('pip install discord.py')!